# I cannot add any scopes through the developer dashboard in the auth tab

Tags: uber-api

In the tutorial, i have been told to select the needed scopes, but it seems that I cannot.

I even have a sentence in my dashboard saying "I do not have all the access, and I need to contact Uber"

Has someone already had this issue where we just cannot add any scopes ?

I tried many browsers

Thank you

Comment: This question might not be a good fit for stack overflow.  As explained in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), this forum is for questions about a specific programming problem, or a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.  It is not for [customer support questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745).  Unless you can provide a [mcve] showing what you tried so far that did not work (without referring to an external resource like "the tutorial"), we're unlikely to be able to help. See: [ask].

Comment: Specifically, if you have an error message stating *I do not have all the access, and I need to contact Uber*, then this is definitely a [customer support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745) and so this is not the appropriate forum to do that.  You need to contact Uber.